# Select words with .domain in textfile with php and preg_match

Tags: php, regex, filter, preg-match

I try so select some name who finish with **.domain**

The filetext is like :

```
.
..
script
truc.domain
machin.domain
```

Fore exemple i want to select **truc.domain** and **machin.domain**

I try this

```
if (preg_match('~$.domain~', $result)){
    echo $result;
}
```

or

```
if (preg_match('/$.domain/', $result)){
    echo $result;
}
```

But it doesn't work...

My second question is in many example i see preg_match with **preg_match('/filter/)** and **preg_match('~filter~')** .

What is the difference between **/** and **~** ?

Comment: Wrong variation of preg_match - you should pass a 3rd parameter to be filled with matches (seems like you're missing the `$subject` argument though). And those are PCRE delimiters.

Comment: only two parameters are obligatory _int preg_match ( string $pattern , string $subject [, array &$matches [, int $flags = 0 [, int $offset = 0 ]]] )_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference between `/` and `~`. You can choose from a wide range of [delimiters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php). The idea is that you can choose a character that is not part of your pattern, so you don't have to escape anything. For example if you wanted to match `3/4` and were using `/` as the delimiter, you'd have to write `/3\/4/`, but with `~` you can write `~3/4~`.

Regarding your problem, you'll have to put the anchor at the position where it's supposed to match. Since it's the end-of-string anchor, it goes at the end. You also might want to escape the `.` or put it in a character class. Otherwise it's going to match any character:

```
/[.]domain$/
```

Note that your match will only contain `.domain`. If you want the entire "name" ending with `.domain` you need to include that in the pattern. I don't know what you define as a name, but if we go with "alphanumeric and underscore" which is the regex-definition of a word character, you can simply prepend `\w+` to include as much of a "word" as possible in front of the `.domain`.

Finally, since you seem to want to find multiple instances of this, and at line endings, not string endings, you need to use `preg_match_all` and the `m` modifier, which makes `$` match line endings as well:

```
if(preg_match_all('/\w+[.]domain$/m', $input, $matches))
{
    print_r($matches[0]);
}
```

That will print

```
Array
(
    [0] => truc.domain
    [1] => machin.domain
)
```

[Working demo.](http://ideone.com/VElJKJ)

To get *only* the part in front of the period, you could either `explode()` these results at `.`, or you could capture the name:

```
if(preg_match_all('/(\w+)[.]domain$/m', $input, $matches))
{
    print_r($matches[0]);
    print_r($matches[1]);
}
```

Will print

```
Array
(
    [0] => truc.domain
    [1] => machin.domain
)
Array
(
    [0] => truc
    [1] => machin
)
```

[Working demo.](http://ideone.com/SJdhgS)

Comment: thx ! for delete the **.domain** i use **str_replace**, but 
thank you for showing me another solution !

Answer (score 2):

Your regex is not correctly build and if you want to return the matching text you have to provide a third parameter to `preg_match` function.

If you want to match the end of the line, your regex must be like this:

```
 if (preg_match('/(.*)\.domain$/', $search_text, $result)){
     echo $result[0]; //Note this is an array, that matches all the pattern
     echo $result[1]; // This is the match of the first subgroup
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

`~` and `/` are both allowed delimiters for regex, you can use approx. any one but space.

`.` means any character, to match a dot you need to escape it

`$` means end of line so your regex should look like:

```
/\.domain$/
```

Comment: Thx for the explications :) i I mixed between **$**